# Web app keeps opening new page in external browser

Tags: javascript, php, ios, browser, progressive-web-apps

I created a very simple website that is meant to be used as a web app on iOS. It has two pages - index.php is a login page, and the form submit action directs you to the second page with graphs and data (see images if confused). I've managed to remove the browser status bar and bottom portion, so the login page looks fine.

The problem is once I click login on the login page, a status bar appears at the top of the next page (see screenshot once again if confused) and I can't seem to find a way to get rid of it. I should also mention that pressing done on that status bar brings me back to the login page.

I've been trying to remove elements on my website to narrow down what's makin the bar appear, and it *seems to be* the form's action = "otherpage.php" that's causing the bar to appear.

Anyone building PWAs or something similar experiencing this and found any explanations/fixes?

This is the code on index.php

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Fitness Tracker</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:300,400,600,700,800,900|Rubik:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Bhaijaan|Fredoka+One|Passion+One|Poiret+One|Pompiere&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <?php require "header.inc";?>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylelogin.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Fitness Tracker</h1>
    <div class = "loginbox">
        <h2>Login</h2>

        <form method = "post" action = "index.php">
            <input required type ="text" placeholder = "Username" name ="user"/>
            <br/>
            <input required type ="password" placeholder = "Password" name = "pass"/>
            <br/>
            <button type = "submit">Log In</button>
        </form> 
    </div>  

    <?php
        require_once('settings.php');
        if(isset($_POST["user"])==true && isset($_POST["pass"])==true){
            $username = $_POST["user"];
            $password = $_POST["pass"];


            $conn = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $database);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE loginuser = '$username' AND loginpass = '$password'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

            if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $_SESSION["userid"] = $row["userid"];
                echo "<script>window.location.href= \"mainpage.php\"</script>";
            }else{
                echo "<p>Enter the right user and pass.</p>";
            }
        }


    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't think the code on the other page will be relevant, so i won't include it.

I should also mention that clicking the login button on the login page actions you to the same page, which has code that then directs you on to the second page if the login details are correct.

Image links to the screenshots for a better picture.
https://ibb.co/XCN3LFw
https://ibb.co/wppg8TB

Comment: It could be down to serving content over insecure/unencrypted HTTP, in which case look into HTTPS and self signed certs (for dev) and how your web server can use this.

Comment: it feels like just an issue with the redirecting paths/methods though. I doubt that it's due to the lack of HTTPs.

Comment: I can' make you do anything my dude, but the bar says "Not Secure" which is the typical message you see for content served over HTTP. Just my hunch.